# Removing many-to-many relationship via update in Vuex-ORM

Tags: relationship, vuex-orm

I'm wondering if it is possible to remove relationships between two models by simply updating a model on one side of the relationship. **Adding new relationships just works fine** but removing seems not to be an option but maybe I am just missing something.
It seems logical that `insertOrUpdate()` does not "delete" nested relationship but maybe there is another function or property so set to get the desired behavior. Unfortunately, searching the docs was not successful.

In my case I configured a `belongsToMany` (m:n) relationship between model "Process" and model "Dependency". The m-n-model inbetween is "MapProcessDependency"

**The Models**

```js
// Dependency.js
export default class Dependency extends Model {
  static entity = 'dependencies'
  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.string('')
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// Process.js
export default class Process extends Model {
  static entity = 'processes'
  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.string(''),
      dependencies: this.belongsToMany(
        Dependency, MapProcessDependency, 'processId', 'dependencyId'
      )
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// MapProcessDependency
export default class MapProcessDependency extends Model {
  static entity = 'mapProcessesDependencies'
  static primaryKey = ['processId', 'dependencyId']
  static fields () {
    return {
      processId: this.attr(null),
      dependencyId: this.attr(null)
    }
  }
}
```

**The Vuex-ORM database**

```json
dependencies: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dep1",
    "$id": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Dep2",
    "$id": "2"
  }
],
processes: [
  {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "MyProc",
    "dependencies": [ /* managed via vuex-orm in mapProcessesDependencies */],
    "$id": "99"
  }
],
mapProcessesDependencies: [
  "[99,1]": {
    "processId": 99,
    "dependencyId": 1,
    "$id": "[99,1]"
  },
  "[99,2]": {
    "processId": 99,
    "dependencyId": 2,
    "$id": "[99,2]"
  }
]
```

**What I want to achieve**

```js
// ...by calling this:
Process.insertOrUpdate({ where: 99, data: {
    "id": 99,
    "name": "MyProc",
    "dependencies": [ 1 ],
} })
```

...is the following result **without** manually calling `MapProcessDependency.delete([99,2])`:

```json
// [...]
mapProcessesDependencies: [
  "[99,1]": {
    "processId": 99,
    "dependencyId": 1,
    "$id": "[99,1]"
  }
  // relationship [99,2] removed
]
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Until Vuex ORM supports cascading, this is your only option.